# My suffix is when you get paid, My infix tells you what I said

Tags: riddle, rhyme

- My prefix is a circle made
- My suffix is when you get paid
- My infix tells you what I said.
- My whole is a wish you made.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is

> '**YEARN**'

---

My prefix is a circle made

> '**YEAR**' - a full circle around the sun

My suffix is when you get paid

> '**EARN**' - earn money

My infix tells you what I said.

> '**EAR**' - picks up sounds

My whole is a wish you made.

> '**YEARN**' means to long for, a.k.a. 'wish'